# Find matching field in an array of objects in an object with go mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go

My mongo database has a structure like this. Given a parent `_id`, for example, `123`, how can I make a query to check if item `abc` exists in its parent `123`?

```
[
  - _id: 123
    name: "item 1"
    items: [
      {
        _id: abc,
        age: 12,
      },
      {
        _id: efg,
        age: 12,
      }
    ]
  ,
  - id: 456
    name: "item 2"
    items: [
      ...
    ]
]
```

I currently have this and I've tried `$elemMatch` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
db.Collection("album").FindOne(context.Background(), bson.M{"_id": parentID})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear if `items` has separate documents, or if it is a nested array in the document. Either case:

If `items` is a nested array in the document, then:

```
bson.M{"_id":parentID,"items._id":"abc"}
```

will find documents whose `_id` is `parentID` and that contains `_id:"abc"` in one of the elements of `items`.